# How do you create an array of pixels in Pygame?

Tags: python, arrays, pygame

According to the [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html#pygame.surfarray.blit_array):

> **pygame.surfarray.blit_array()**
>   Blit directly from array values
>   *blit_array(Surface, array) -> None*
>   Directly copy values from an
>   array into a Surface ...
>   The array must be the same dimensions as the
>   Surface and will completely replace all pixel values. Only integer,
>   ascii character and record arrays are accepted.

My code is as follows,

```
surf = pygame.display.set_mode( ( width, height ) )
pixels = [
   # width * height * 3
   [(255,241,232),(255,241,232),...],
   [(255,241,232),(255,241,232),...],
   ...
]
surfarray.blit_array( surf, pixels )
```

Running it, I get the error `ValueError: list object does not export an array buffer`.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Here's the full error message,

```
line 23, in <module>    
  surfarray.blit_array( surf, pixels )
line 81, in blit_array
  return numpysf.blit_array (surface, array)
line 82, in blit_array
  return array_to_surface(surface, array)
ValueError: list object does not export an array buffer
```

Comment: Is this `[(255,241,232),(255,241,232),...]` the exact code or you have pasted it here for the sake of readability

Comment: @ZdaR It's truncated. The actual array is 500 * 300 * 3 in size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array for `pygame.surfarray.blit_array()` must be any array object, either a np.array or  numeric array. A array made from list doesn't work in this case, but you can do:

```
import numpy as np
pixels = np.array([
   [(255,241,232),(255,241,232)],
   [(255,241,232),(255,241,232)]
])
#rest the same...
```

Which converts your list array to a np.array

In the documentation for pygame.surfarray it states:

> Functions to convert pixel data between pygame Surfaces and arrays.
>   This module will only be functional when pygame can use the external
>   Numpy package.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!